# Groovy declaring a variable

Tags: groovy, string-interpolation

I want to set the below details in HTTP Body content through the script.

```
def clientId ='ddfgertg'
def clientSecret='fghghfghfgh'
```

and I want to set the above value in the below string variable

```
def httpBody = '{ "Client_ID": "${clientId}", "Client_Secret":"${clientSecret}", "Grant_Type":"client_credentials" }'
```

when I print the httpBody it not set the `clinetId`, `clientSecret` value in that.

my actual output

```
{ "Client_ID": "${clientId}", "Client_Secret":"${clientSecret}", "Grant_Type":"client_credentials" }
```

Expected output

```
{ "Client_ID": "ddfgertg", "Client_Secret":"fghghfghfgh", "Grant_Type":"client_credentials" }
```

Comment: You need to use double quotes for string interpolation to work, I think. See https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation

Comment: Doing this will work: `def httpBody = "{ \"Client_ID\": \"${clientId}\", \"Client_Secret\":\"${clientSecret}\", \"Grant_Type\":\"client_credentials\" }"`

Comment: groovy has many options for creating string literals.  find one that uses GroovyStrings so it supports interpolation, and which lets you specify double-quotes without escaping. see https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#all-strings

Answer (score 0):

Just turn ' to """, like:

```
def httpBody = """{ "Client_ID": "${clientId}", "Client_Secret":"${clientSecret}", "Grant_Type":"client_credentials" }"""
```

it will be ok.